# Run rollback when checksum is changed for changeset in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I see an attribute runOnChange that re-runs changeset when it is changed. But is it possible to apply a rollback for this changeset before re-applying automatically?
For example, I have a script that is called from changeset. I made some changes there and want to re-apply, but before it rollback need to be called and after it new version of the script should be applied.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature to automatically roll back a changeSet on checksum change. Not sure if it is possible in general because if the configuration has changed you don't know what the old value was to roll back.

Depending on what you are doing in your script and your database, can roll back the changes manually in the script and use the liquibase runOnChange="true" changeSet flag.

For example, if you have a script that creates a stored procedure, you could use <changeSet runOnChange="true"> and then define your procedure as "CREATE OR REPLACE"

If you have a script that defines a view, you could add a <sql>IF EXISTS VIEW_NAME DROP VIEW VIEW_NAME</sql>

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. I understand your idea. Now we have such approach: all scripts are not repeatable, they have no such checs, when script is changed new combined rollback is applied, and after it compined migration script is started. As a first step of the migration I want to run all scripts separately using liquibase calling the same ddl/dml scripts - so if some of them changes I need at first to write a rollback script.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. If it is easier to get into deails outside of the stackoverflow comments you can contact me at nathan AT liquibase.org